# SQL query to return a column value where another column is minimum per serial number

Tags: sql, case, min

I have a table as follows and would like a query to give me the a new column: First Site.
Table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Serial_No | Production_Date |   Production_Site |   First_Site
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 11 June 2013    |   SiteA           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 12 June 2013    |   SiteB           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 12 June 2013    |   SiteC           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 10 June 2013    |   SiteA           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 14 July 2013    |   SiteB           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 14 July 2013    |   SiteC           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 9 May 2013      |   SiteA           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
003       | 5 June 2013     |   SiteB           |   SiteB
--------------------------------------------------------------
003       | 19 July 2013    |   SiteC           |   SiteB
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The First_Site column reads each serial number, finds the earliest production date for that serial number, and outputs the Site which corresponds to the earliest date.

I've tried the following query but they do not give me the result I want:

```
SELECT
Case When ( Production_Date ) = ( MIN( Production_Date ) 
OVER (PARTITION BY ( Serial_No)) ) 
Then (Production_Site) Else 'Null') End AS First_Site
FROM Table
```

This gives me the correct value for rows where the Production_Date is minimum per serial number, but gives null values for the other rows of the serial number:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Serial_No | Production_Date |   Production_Site |   First_Site
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 11 June 2013    |   SiteA           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 12 June 2013    |   SiteB           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 12 June 2013    |   SiteC           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
001       | 10 June 2013    |   SiteA           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 14 July 2013    |   SiteB           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 14 July 2013    |   SiteC           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
002       | 9 May 2013      |   SiteA           |   SiteA
--------------------------------------------------------------
003       | 5 June 2013     |   SiteB           |   SiteB
--------------------------------------------------------------
003       | 19 July 2013    |   SiteC           |   Null
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which is not what I want. My guess is I have to change the ELSE part of my case statement. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I'm using Oracle DBMS

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Serial_No int, Production_Date datetime, Production_Site varchar(50), First_Site varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #table VALUES(001, '11 June 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(001, '12 June 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(001, '12 June 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(001, '10 June 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(002, '14 July 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(002, '14 July 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(002, '9 May 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(003, '5 June 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteB')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES(003, '19 July 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteB')

SELECT 
    main.*
    ,(
        SELECT MIN(Production_Date) 
        FROM #table AS sub 
        WHERE main.Serial_No = sub.Serial_No
    ) AS Earliest_Production_Date
FROM
    #table as main
```

But i guess this looks nicer:

```
SELECT 
    main.*
    ,MIN(Production_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial_No)
FROM
    #table as main
```

Or if you want more data from the earliest production:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        main.*
        ,MIN(Production_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial_No) AS Earliest_Production_Date
    FROM
        #table as main
)
SELECT
    cte.*
    ,t.First_Site AS Earliest_First_Site
FROM
    cte
    INNER JOIN #table AS t ON 
        t.Serial_No = cte.Serial_No 
        and t.Production_Date = cte.Earliest_Production_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table First_Site (serial_no varchar(20), production_date varchar(20), production_site varchar(20), first_site varchar(22))

insert into First_Site select '001', '11 June 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '001', '12 June 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '001', '12 June 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '001', '10 June 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '002', '14 July 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '002', '14 July 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '002', '9 May 2013', 'SiteA', 'SiteA'
insert into First_Site select '003', '5 June 2013', 'SiteB', 'SiteB'
insert into First_Site select '003', '19 June 2013', 'SiteC', 'SiteB'

SELECT fs.serial_no, fs.production_date, A.dt, fs.production_site, fs.first_site FROM first_site fs
JOIN 
(
    SELECT serial_no, MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME, production_date)) dt , first_site
    FROM first_site 
    GROUP BY serial_no, first_site
)A ON a.dt = fs.production_date 
AND A.first_site = fs.first_site
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
SELECT main.*, sub.production_site as first_site 
FROM t main INNER JOIN t sub ON main.serial_no = sub.serial_no
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (select * from t 
   where serial_no = sub.serial_no and production_date < sub.production_date);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79d962/4

The only issue with this code has is that if you can have several sites for same serial number on same date, you will end up with two records.